# Grep specific word

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to grep a specific word from a line present in a file. For example:

```
Servers="abc_servername_12345:12345"
```

From the above line I want to grep only
`abc_servername_12345` from this line present in the file.
`abc_servername_12345` keeps changing based on server name like `xzy_servername_78964`.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -oP 'Servers="\K[^:]*' file
```

The above line should do.

If your grep doesn't support `-P`, you can try this sed line:

```
sed -n '/^Servers=/{s/[^"]*"//;s/:.*//;p}' file
```

Comment: Thanks soo much can you please explain this so i can implement similer type

Comment: the code explains itself @user10042227.  if you don't know `sed` I suggest you reading some man page, info page or tutorials